# Start the camera on a new FirstPersonCharacter when we click on play button

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm a beginner in Unreal Engine 4 and I need your assistance. Could you please tell me how I can launch a game on Unreal Engine 4 (when clicking on the play button) using the new Player camera that I have added to the viewport?

In fact, I have added a new FirstPersonCharacter to my map, but I am unable to launch the game using the camera from this FirstPersonCharacter (as described below).
[image]

I have searched everywhere, but I couldn't find where the field corresponding to the game's camera (at launch) is referenced.
I have tried using the EventBeginPlay, but I no longer have control over my character.

Thank you in advance for your help.